# Fastlane build saying that ProviderScope not found

Tags: firebase, fastlane, riverpod, firebase-app-distribution

I tried releasing the app to firebase app distribution using fastlane and when I run the app, it throws an error saying that ProviderScope is not found. The app has been made on top of Riverpod state management.

When I run the app in debug or release mode, it works absolutely fine. Furthermore, I also created a manual build an it also magically works perfectly. Just having issue with Firebase App Distribution.

Comment: Probably you have multiple entry points? Could you show what your `main.dart` file looks like before the `ProviderScope` widget?

Comment: Thanks @Ruble that was the issue! I was having multiple entry points and it was using wrong main.dart file to create the build

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I suggested, and later as *Shrijan Regmi* pointed out, the problem was in multiple entry points, i.e. there are multiple different `main.dart` files. And the wrong entry point was used for the build.